# Why my navbar toggler button from bootstrap don't show the list of nav items?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navigation

I have this code in html and i want to show de nav items when the navbar collapse, because is not showing anything when a press the toogler button.

```
        <div class="container-fluid ">
            <a class="navbar-brand nav-color">
                > $ / kromabyte /~
            </a>
            <span class="logo__cursor"></span>
            
            <button class="navbar-toggler " type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-color " aria-current="page" href="#">index /</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-color" href="#about">About /</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-color" href="#">Portfolio /</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link nav-color">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to change these props for the toggler button:

- data-bs-toggle="collapse" to data-toggle="collapse"
- data-bs-target="#navbarNav" to data-target="#navbarNav"

Hope this can help.

Comment: hi, i already fixed, the problem was that i don´t install de jquery from bootstrap, but thanks for your help.